# How do you take the sum of an Eigen matrix of chars while avoiding overflows?

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

I am new to the [Eigen C++ library](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page).

I would like to take the summation of a matrix filled with 8 bit integers, and place the result into a matrix of 32 bit integers in order to avoid overflow.

I would also like to avoid casting.  For example, here is a solution that uses casting:

```
Eigen::Matrix<uint8_t, 2, 2> input;
Eigen::Matrix<uint32_t, 2, 1> summation;
input << 255, 255,
           3, 4;
summation = input.cast<uint32_t>().colwise().sum();  // [258, 259]
```

Also, note that this would be an easy for-loop to write manually, however, I would like to take advantage of SIMD instructions.

Is there a way to take a column-wise summation of `uint8_t` that avoids casting and uses SIMD instructions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that thanks to expression templates, the cast operation does not create a temporary, and the resulting code will be as accumulating `uint8_t` within a `uint32_t` through a manual loop.

Comment: I see, so the solution as written will not be casting `input` into a `uint32_t` first?

Comment: @jdg It will cast elements individually (i.e., lazy) and add them together. At no time it will cast the entire matrix at once. Also note, that integer SIMD in Eigen is currently not implemented, if types other than `int32_t` are involved (your compiler might auto-vectorize, however).